# Escaping Node.JS MySQL Issues

Tags: mysql, node.js, wordpress, parsing, random

Im creating a daemon that automatically changes MYSQL table contents randomly around my pages. (wordpress tables)

I have a array of stories that the system will read and then UPDATE the mysql in the tables, and as well update the timestamp on the server.

My code looks like this

```
//required libraries
fs = require('fs')
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();

//mysql table
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'yomamabinshoppin',
  user     : 'nonya',
  password : 'defineltynonya',
  database : 'okbye'
});


connection.connect();


//sitelisting
var sites = [ 'wp_counlwarehouseposts', 'wp_infounlwarehouseposts', 'wp_infowarehouse31posts', 'wp_netunlwarehouseposts', 'wp_netwarehouse31posts', 'wp_orgunlwarehouseposts', 'wp_orgwarehouse31posts', 'wp_stagcomwarehouseposts', 'wp_stagcowarehouseposts', 'wp_staginfwarehouseposts', 'wp_stagnetwarehouseposts', 'wp_stagorgwarehouseposts'];

//select story from catalogue
function ss (id,callback){
    fs.readFile('./' + id +'.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
   callback(data);
});}

sites.forEach(function(entry) {
    ss(Math.floor(Math.random() * 12), function (returnvalue){
    fs.writeFile(entry, returnvalue);
    connection.query("UPDATE  `warehous_wordpress`.`"+entry+"` SET  `post_date` =  '"+ dateFormat(now, "yyyy-m-d") +" 01:00:01' WHERE `"+entry+"`.`ID` =1", function(err, rows, fields) {

 if (err) throw err;


});
 fs.appendFile('postlog.log', "UPDATE `warehous_wordpress`.`"+entry+"` SET `post_content` = '"+returnvalue+"' WHERE `"+entry+"`.`ID` = 1" , function (err) {

});
connection.query("UPDATE `warehous_wordpress`.`"+entry+"` SET `post_content` = '"+returnvalue+"' WHERE `"+entry+"`.`ID` = 1", function(err, rows, fields) {

 if (err) throw err;
 });

});


});
```

The issue in question here is at the line of

```
fs.appendFile('postlog.log', "UPDATE `warehous_wordpress`.`"+entry+"` SET `post_content` = '"+returnvalue+"' WHERE `"+entry+"`.`ID` = 1" , function (err) {

});
```

Where returnvalue is my story, and where entry is the current table name.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th
at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 're
 frightened can become a safety issue. When designing something to scare visit'
at line 1
```

The story that it is referring to has the text of this.

```
SCARE PEOPLE THE RIGHT WAY.
"We always try to scare forward to try to keep the flow going," Travis says. "A lot of times we try to scare further down the path rather than being scared into the wall," which slows the circulation of traffic through the maze.
Plus, where people instinctively move when they're frightened can become a safety issue. When designing something to scare visitors, you have to think about how people will react—and what they might jump into if they leaped backward in terror. "You never really know how bad something is going to scare somebody," Travis explains. "We try to keep the opposite wall clear from any kind of metal props or anything like that."
```

At first i thought the issue was related to some html in my stories, so i removed ALL of the html in the stories, same issue was happening.

Any advice to how i could fix this?
Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**
After escaping the variables for the Query, the modified code, still the same parsing issue on the SQL end

```
//required libraries
fs = require('fs')
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();

//mysql table
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
});


connection.connect();


//sitelisting
var sites = [ 'wp_counlwarehouseposts', 'wp_infounlwarehouseposts', 'wp_infowarehouse31posts', 'wp_netunlwarehouseposts', 'wp_netwarehouse31posts', 'wp_orgunlwarehouseposts', 'wp_orgwarehouse31posts', 'wp_stagcomwarehouseposts', 'wp_stagcowarehouseposts', 'wp_staginfwarehouseposts', 'wp_stagnetwarehouseposts', 'wp_stagorgwarehouseposts'];

//select story from catalogue
function ss (id,callback){
    fs.readFile('./' + id +'.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
   callback(data);
});}

sites.forEach(function(entry) {
    ss(Math.floor(Math.random() * 12), function (returnvalue){
    fs.writeFile(entry, returnvalue);
    connection.query("UPDATE  `warehous_wordpress`.`"+entry+"` SET  `post_date` =  '"+ dateFormat(now, "yyyy-m-d") +" 01:00:01' WHERE `"+entry+"`.`ID` =1", function(err, rows, fields) {

 if (err) throw err;


});
 fs.appendFile('postlog.log', "UPDATE `warehous_wordpress`.`"+ entry + "` SET `post_content` = '"+ mysql.escape(returnvalue) +"' WHERE `"+ entry +"`.`ID` = 1" , function (err) {

});
connection.query("UPDATE `warehous_wordpress`.`"+ entry +"` SET `post_content` = '" + mysql.escape(returnvalue) + "' WHERE `"+ entry +"`.`ID` = 1", function(err, rows, fields) {

 if (err) throw err;
 });

});


});
```

Comment: Step 1: Use [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com). Step 2: Learn about [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com). Step 3: Use placeholder statements in Sequelize.

Comment: Another thing to note here is to lean less on copy/paste and use variables to preserve things like query strings that are printed or used more than once. Having two identical bits of code means doing twice the work to make changes.

Comment: Check the [Escaping query values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) section of the `mysql` module. **Never** write something like `'"+returnvalue+"'`. If the variable contains a `'` then your whole query fails, like in your example with the `they're`. Not only that it will fail, but you are also vulnerable to mysql injections.

Comment: After escaping all variables in the query, i receive the same parser error.

Comment: @ChristopherAllen Then you should show your updated code.

Comment: @t.niese Sorry about that, code is updated. I couldn't escape the entry variable as it changed the text of it. But the returnvalue has been escaped.

Comment: You should read the documentation carefully. If you use `mysql.escape` then the quotes are added for you if they are required, so you have to write: `= " + mysql.escape(returnvalue) + " WHERE` **without** the surrounding `'`.

Comment: @t.niese This worked, attention to detail. if you want to make this a question so i can give you some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always escape your variables correctly.

If your `returnvalue` is `they're` then this portion of your query:

```
SET `post_content` = '" + returnvalue + "' WHERE
```

will become:

```
SET `post_content` = 'they're' WHERE
```

As you can see, this will result into a syntax error at `'re`

In the worst case this can be used to inject some data into your database. If `returnvalue` e.g. would be `they', ID='1`, then your query will be:

```
SET `post_content` = 'they', ID='1' WHERE
```

So you **always** have to [escape](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) you values, either using `?`  or `mysql.escape`

Using `??` and `?`:

```
connection.query(
  "UPDATE `warehous_wordpress`.?? SET `post_content` = ? WHERE ??.`ID` = 1",
  [entry, returnvalue, entry] , 
  function(err, rows, fields) {});
```

Using `mysql.escapeId` and `mysql.escape`:

```
connection.query(
    "UPDATE `warehous_wordpress`." + mysql.escapeId(entry) +
    " SET `post_content` = " + mysql.escape(returnvalue) + 
    " WHERE " + mysql.escapeId(entry) + ".`ID` = 1",
    function(err, rows, fields) {});
```

I would suggest you to use `?` and `??`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var async = require('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    ...
});
connection.connect();

var sites = [ 'wp_counlwarehouseposts', 'wp_infounlwarehouseposts', ...];

function copyFile(source, target, callback) {
    var rs = fs.createReadStream(source);
    rs.on('error', callback);

    var ws = fs.createWriteStream(target);
    ws.on('error', callback);
    ws.on('close', callback);
    rs.pipe(wr);
}

function updateSite(site, callback) {
    copyFile('./' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) +'.txt', site, function(err) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err);

        connection.query(
            'UPDATE  warehous_wordpress.? SET post_date = ? WHERE ?.ID=1', 
            [site, dateFormat(now, 'yyyy-m-d') + ' 01:00:01', site], 
            callback
        );
    });
}

async.eachSeries(sites, updateSite, function (err) { if (err) throw err; });
```

Comment: Identifiers have to be escaped with `??`  and not with `?`.